# error in webdev while upgrading dart to 2.7

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to migrate a web application from 2.52 to 2.7, however, a lot of error are thrown without much information.
The problem seems to upgrade the build_runner and build_web_compilers.
Since 2.6, it must use dill files to compile and that type of compilation is not working for my projects.

webdev version: 2.5.4

here is the log:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Jonathan-941:guaraci jonathanrezende$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.7.0 (Fri Dec 6 16:26:51 2019 +0100) on "macos_x64"
MacBook-Pro-de-Jonathan-941:guaraci jonathanrezende$ webdev --version
2.5.4
MacBook-Pro-de-Jonathan-941:guaraci jonathanrezende$ sudo webdev serve web:80 --hostname guara.ci
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 3.8s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms
[INFO] Serving `web` on http://guara.ci
[INFO] Generating SDK summary completed, took 3.5s
[SEVERE]build_web_compilers:ddc on package:oni_services_components/src/communication_message.ddc.module: Error compiling dartdevc module:oni_services_components|lib/src/communication_message.ddc.js

Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/oni_forms.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/oni_forms.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/base.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/base.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/base.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/batch_form.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/batch_form.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/editor/base.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/editor/base.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/editor/editor.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/editor/editor.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/editor/editor.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/error.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/footer.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/footer.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/footer.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/form.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/form.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/form.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/group.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/group.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/object_form.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/object_form.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/paginated_form.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/paginated_form.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/submit.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_forms' in 'package:oni_forms/src/submit.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/oni_objector.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/oni_objector.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/src/field_desc.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/src/field_desc.scss.css.shim.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/src/field_desc.template.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/src/object.dart'.
Error: Could not resolve the package 'oni_objector' in 'package:oni_objector/src/object.template.dart'.

[WARNING]build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart: Unable to read oni_services_components|lib/src/communication_message.ddc.js, check your console or the `.dart_tool/build/generated/oni_services_components/lib/src/communication_message.ddc.js.errors` log file.
[SEVERE]build_web_compilers:ddc on package:oni_inputs/oni_inputs.template.ddc.module: Error creating oni_inputs|lib/oni_inputs.template.ddc.dillError creating kernel summary for module:oni_inputs|lib/oni_inputs.template.ddc.dill

Response:--dart-sdk-summary=file:///Users/jonathanrezende/Dart/current/lib/_internal/ddc_sdk.dill --output=/private/tmp/scratch_spacenF5cNh/packages/oni_inputs/oni_inputs.template.ddc.dill --packages-file=file:///tmp/kernel_builder_jpDCb2/.packages --multi-root-scheme=org-dartlang-app --exclude-non-sources --summary-only --target=ddc --libraries-file=file:///Users/jonathanrezende/Dart/current/lib/libraries.json --reuse-compiler-result --use-incremental-compiler --used-inputs=/tmp/kernel_builder_FBcKpI/used_inputs.txt --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/src/bootstrap/modules.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/utils/id_generator/id_generator.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/oni_front_common/oni_front_common.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/material_input_default_value_accessor.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/laminate/components/modal/modal.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/src/runtime/proxies.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/material_input.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/dynamic_component/dynamic_component.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/oni_common/oni_common.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/oni_front_common/src/config.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/angular_components.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/material_auto_suggest_input.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/base_material_input.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/src/runtime/queries.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_select/material_select.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/src/runtime/text_binding.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/focus/focus.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/src/material_tooltip/tooltip_controller.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/utils/angular/reference/reference.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/utils/browser/dom_service/dom_service.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/model/selection/selection_container.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/interfaces/has_disabled.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/oni_services/src/action.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/angular.template.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/mixins/material_dropdown_base.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/material_auto_suggest_input.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_input/deferred_validator.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/src/laminate/popup/popup_hierarchy.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/utils/disposer/disposer.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_forms/src/directives.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/angular.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular/src/core/change_detection/change_detection.ddc.dill --input-summary=org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/model/ui/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it out.
was a cyclic dependency between deep related packages.

I am guessing the old DDC let this happen because even thought the packages were cyclic, the files were not.
Now, the dill stuff does not let this happen in the package level.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same problem, but I can't figure out what you mean by "cyclic dependency between deep related packages" and how did you process to elemeintate this without changing the code too much ? Is it only by modifying the pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Package A included package B, package B included C and package C include package A. So A -> B, B -> C, C -> A, making it cyclic. I had to move some files around and change some imports and then it worked. I suggest you do the same because it is really more organized to not let this kind of cyclic dependency to happen. My problem was happening with components, maybe it happens only with components declared files

Comment: Seems like there is a lake of documentation on why this worked defore and how to detect this. the error message isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see `oni_forms` in your .packages file? This looks like you got some new version of a package that is missing dependencies and not a build_web_compilers issue.

Comment: yes it is     oni_forms:../../../oni-group/web/oni_forms/lib/

Comment: the point regarding build_web_compilers is that it doesn't happen with dart2js and when I use build_web_compilers < 2.0